# Thin-wedge Interference Problems (Classical Waves Problem)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, interference

I would like to solve the problem on the following image:

[image]

My question is: Why is the answer to (a) a minimum?

1. When the light wave hits the top surface of the top glass, a wave will be reflected with phase change of pi.
2. The non-reflected goes to the bottom surface of the top glass to be reflected again with no phase change.
3. The non-reflected part still goes to the top of the down glass and is reflected with phase change pi.
4. We don't care about other reflections as amplitude diminishes too much.

Now, We have three waves who are reflected towards our eye. 2 and 3 automatically cancel each other. There is only wave 1 left. So, this is not perfectly destructive. How can they call this a minimum?

Comment: Please help me out here. I am lost.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, any idea?

Comment: What's the phase change in the space between the two glass plates?

Comment: pi. The two waves 2 and 3 cancel each other out. But wave 1 still stays. So how come it is a minima?

Comment: OK, I think I see your problem. In this case minimum doesn't mean total extinction. It just means that there is a visible variation in brightness. You can easily do this experiment yourself with some reasonably flat glass plates. As a kid I used to do it with glass from slide holders. It can probably be done nicely with microscope slides. What you will see in white light is a number of faint colored fringes. If you wanted near total extinction rather than slight variations in intensity, you would need mirrored and coated surfaces to get just one reflection. Does that help?

Comment: Ok. That solves a part of the problem. But how do I know it is a minimum and not a maximum. How can I know there is not destructive interference between wave 1,2 and 3 just right of the intersection of the glasses?

Comment: My best guess is that if they are giving this as a simple (homework) question, then they want you to forget about the other surfaces. In reality, of course, one would have to add all four single reflections and the waves from multiple reflections. But since glass typically reflects about 4% if the incident light (as long as we are far away from the Brewster angle), the secondary reflections are much weaker. Try with the simple two wave solution and see if that gets you the points. That's what I would do.

Comment: So, I just assume that I can ignore wave 1? I just take into account the interference of 2 and 3 and call that the resulting pattern?
Isn't this taking a wild guess!?

Comment: Well, you could pretend that the top and bottom surfaces of the stack are coated with an anti-reflective coating, and then the experimental result would be a two wave interference. Or you can do the full four wave calculation. There is no need for guessing in either case. All terms that have to do with the thickness of the two plates will include d_plate, while all terms that depend exclusively on the gap will have a d_gap in it. Furthermore, you can calculate the intensities and use only the strongest interference terms, which also takes the guesswork out of it.

Comment: On a more general level problems like these are meant to make you comfortable with approximation and to let go of wanting to calculate the exact solution. I remember that in one class the TA decided to smuggle Bogoliubov transformations into a problem without telling us the first thing about them. Most of the class flopped on that one, of course, and the two best theorists gnawed their way trough the math and then complained bitterly to the TA "What the f... did we have to do that for?" (excuse my language).

Comment: Gah! I still don't understand :( You guys are putting so much effort onto the help. I feel bad for you :S In my head, I just don't understand why we can simply ignore the first reflected wave 1. I mean it's always going to be there.

Comment: OK... maybe you should consider a career other than physics then? You don't seem to be comfortable with the main concept of simplification and approximation. :-(

Comment: Gah. I got an email from my TA: She said: we are only looking at waves 2 and 3 because if we were looking at 1 and 2, we would be searching for destructive interference along all the surface of the wedge, not only the intersection. This confuses me more!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start, and in context of question (a), you can simplify the situation by thinking it as two glass slabs parallel to each other with an air interface of neglictible thickness between them.

I'll consider only what happens in the first slab as by symmetry, what happens in the second one is the same.

Now, first:
**All the light you want to consider is the light that goes *into* the slabs.** 
In effect, each time light meets an interface, part of it is transmitted and part of it is reflected. So think about the part of the light that is first transmitted through the top interface of the top glass (which is the great majority of it). Then, when it goes to the bottom*, part of it is transmitted and the rest is reflected back into the slab. This happens an infinite number of times (every time with a decreased intensity) on both interfaces so that in the end, the the light that comes back out from the slabs to your eyes is the majority of the light. Therefore, you can neglect your first bullet point. (I recommend you to look up the maths in your textbook, it's only a sum of an arithmetic progression if my memory doesn't betray me).

Second: **Magic happens at the interface of both of the slabs.** Go back to the * in the previous paragraph. At that time, *two* reflexions occur: one from the bottom of the top slab (with no phase shift as it is a glass/air interface) and one from the top of the bottom slab (with a phase shift as it is an air/glass interface). As we consider the air thickness to be neglictible, we obtain two waves with a Pi phase shift that destructively interfere. All you have to do is prove that the intensities of both of these are comparable (with the aforementioned sums) so that you can detect a minimum.

Hope that helps

**EDIT**

[image]

This image (taken from the book *Introduction to Optics* by Pedrotti) illustrates what I mention in the first paragraph of my explanation: after multiple reflections and transmissions, the intensities of the rays add up. With this, you can figure out the sum I mentionned by yourself.

The *r* and *t* respectively stand for the reflection and transmission coefficients. Be careful with the *t* though as it is also used for the thickness of the slab (on the right side of the picture).

Comment: Mary, I don't understand why I can neglect "When the light wave hits the top surface of the top glass, a wave will be reflected with phase change of pi." It is still a wave!

Comment: "the majority of the light" : Does that not contradict what @CuriousOne said about light 4% reflection?

Comment: @yolo123 I don't have time to go into details right now but think in terms of intensities. This is in agreement with the 4% you mention: I said that the majority of the light is transmitted, isn't 96% the majority?

Comment: Oh... But what would happen if we were to replace the air inside the wedge with a material of, say, n=1.7? Would we still have 28 dark fringes?